# Multiplying weight matrix of a trained neural network with a test vector

Tags: matlab, neural-network, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I trained the perceptron neural network and obtained the weight matrix using matlab.

The dimension of the obtained weight matrix is <50x1 double>

Now while giving the test input, I have a <1x1 double> value, that need's to be tested.

If I multiply the weight matrix with the value, I get <50x1 double>. How can I set threshold for <50x1 double> value.

Is there any way to get around this problem ?

This is the code

```
tic
clc; clear all; close all; 
%function [ w1, bias ] = percep1( x )

zzz = xlsread('D:\matlab\NN_FILES\train_mean.xlsx')
s = zzz;
learning_rate = 0.1; % go with the loop mohan
theta = 10000;
w1=0; 
for j = 1:50
    x=s(:,j);t=1; bias=0; stopp=1; count=0;
while stopp
    yin = bias + (w1*x);
    % activation function
    if yin > theta
         y = 1;
    elseif yin < -theta
        y = -1;
    else
        y = 0;
    end


    if (t ~= y)
    %     for i = 1 : 7
            %if ( x(i) ~= 0 )
                w1 = w1 + ( learning_rate * t * x);
            %end
    %    end
        bias = bias + ( learning_rate * t);
    end

    count = count + 1;

    if t==y
       stopp = 0;
       count;
    end
 end

 w(j,:) = w1;
 b1(j) = bias;
 e1(j) = count;
 end
 new_weights_2 = w(50,:)
 yyy= xlsread('D:\matlab\NN_FILES\test_mean.xlsx');
 st=yyy;
 theta2 = 1.0e+04 * 1.2 ;
 for j=1:20
     x=st(:,j);
     yin=(new_weights_2(1))*(x)
     output(j) = yin;     
     if yin > theta2
         y = 1;
     elseif yin < -theta2
         y = -1;
     else y = 0;
 end
 y1(j)=y;

end
toc
```

Now I have used only the first value of the weight matrix inorder to satisfy the multiplication rule. Is there any way to multiply the weight matrix with the test input ?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you are doing? Not the whole code but the final step with multiplication including variable size and class.

Comment: Your perceptron seems to map 7 input to 50 output. So clearly you need a 7 input vector at input, and a weighting function to map the 50 element output for comparison with a threshold, indicating true/false value. Seems like you may not be getting all details of your algorithm right. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron

Comment: @yuk I have updated the question with the full code. Could you please assist me.

Comment: @Arcturus I have edited the question with the full code. Sorry for the change in the dimension of the weight matrix. I am having trouble in setting the threshold while testing the input.

Comment: Let's say matrix is A, and scalar is b. To get matrix C were each element of matrix A is multiplied with b you should execute: C=A.*b. I guess this is what you want to do. Or?

Comment: @aircooled ok then, I will be having a 50x1 vector output. How will I be able to set the threshold ?

Comment: @Mrk you need to find a another 50x1 matrix, say rand(50,1) and take its dot-product to get a linear value, or you can use sum() to reduce 50x1 into a scalar. Now go with the threshold. Ofcourse I'm totally oblivious to your use, and what this means for your algorithm!

Comment: @Arcturus The algorithm is used for classification. Let me use sum() to make it a scalar and see how it classifies.